# Multilayer relational data retrieval Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So i have 3 models: User, Team, Project

User ManyToMany Team.
Team ManyToMany Project.

I need to Retrieve the data from all project, based on the current user and his corresponding teams.

i tried writing it as a oneLiner:
$user->teams->projects
Error: Property [projects] does not exist on this collection instance.

but that didn't work. Is it possible as a oneliner or does it need to be used in a foreach loop

Comment: Could you please provide more code details? Your relationships and what you want to accomplish, if you want to know all projects for an user or just related to a team. For instance, to get all projects from the first team related to that user could you try to do: dd($user->teams()->first()->projects()->get()) to see if that works?

Comment: @mmarques Query i need: 
    `$user->teams()->get()->projects()->get()`.

aka: i need to get all projects from all teams from a certain user.

Answer (score 0):

Solved By using this nested Foreach Loop:

```
    $user = auth()->guard('api')->user();
    if (!$user->hasRole(['directie', 'administrator'])) {
        $collection = collect();
        foreach ($user->teams as $team) {
            foreach ($team->projects()->with('customer')->get() as $project) {
                $collection->push($project);
            }
        }
        $unique = $collection->unique('id');
        return new ProjectCollection($unique);
    }
    return new ProjectCollection(Project::with("customer")->paginate(13));
```